# Do the roots of R(x) have any significance for the prime counting function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm calculating the roots of the function 
\begin{equation}
R(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}li(x^{1/k})
\end{equation}
This function seems to have a largest and smallest positive root. Can anyone tell me if the roots of $R(x)$ have any significance for the prime counting function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. If you have not already, see the paper by Folkmar Bornemann that describes a method for finding the roots of R(x) (see link below). It's a very interesting method.

Best regards,

Tom

[Paper](http://www-m3.ma.tum.de/m3old/bornemann/challengebook/AppendixD/waldvogel_problem_solution.pdf)

Comment: The first lemma of this paper seems to making the assumption that the zeros of the zeta-function are all simple (without explicitly stating it).